# C#: Access SQL view through generic RepositoryBase class?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, generics

I'm using a RepositoryBase<T> base class as the foundation for my individual repositories (e.g. UserRepository).

It simplifies things like adding new entities etc. for example:

```
public IQueryable<T> SelectAll()
{
     return db.GetTable<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
}
```

Now I've added a view "UserActive" in my database. Is there any way to access the view in a similar manner, e.g. if T = User then I want to return the db.UsersActive view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a special one-off case, you could do:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(User))
{
    return db.GetView<UserActive>().AsQueryable<UserActive>();
}
else
{
    return db.GetTable<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
}
```

This of course makes an assumption on how you would access your useractive view using your linq provider :-P YMMV